# Create core dump only when a systemd service dies with a specific signal (segmentation fault)

Tags: systemd, signals, core-dump, segmentation-fault

I have some services running in systemd on Ubuntu 18.04 which very occasionally crash with a segfault (11/SIGSEGV). Is it possible to configure it to create a core dump only for SIGSEGV and not when the services die in other ways (e.g. 6/ABRT)?